# Multiple Androids with one bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, external-keyboard

Is there some software that simply lets me use one bluetooth keyboard to type on several different android tablets in front of me?

Provided:
The keyboard supports pairing with multiple devices, and it is paired with all of my tablets.

A solution to this problem should ideally give a way for me to choose which tablet is currently receiving keyboard input using only the keyboard; in other words, I shouldn't have to touch a screen in order to switch to another tablet.

Answer (score 1):

No. Although the keyboard can *pair* with multiple devices, it can only be *connected* to one at a time. You can't fix that with software that runs on the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of software that will allow any given keyboard to pair with multiple devices at a time, but the Logitech Bluetooth Multi-Device Keyboard K480 will do that. It has a wheel to cycle through and choose which device you want to use.